# What is the right metric type if I want to emit number of results of a query, as datadog metric?

Tags: datadog

My daemon keeps querying db on a cronly basis. In every iteration, (a) the deamon makes a DB query (b) receives some documents from db (c) processes those results. I want to emit *the number of documents returned for the query* on Datadog. What is the right metric type?

Answer (score 4):

[Gauge metric](https://docs.datadoghq.com/developers/metrics/#gauges) types will do the job here given that your query does not run more than once within 10 seconds. If that is not the case, go for [count metric](https://docs.datadoghq.com/developers/metrics/#count)

The flush interval in datadog by default is 10 seconds, if you use a **gauge metric** and the metric is reported more than once in a flush interval, datadog agent only sends the last value ignoring the previous ones. For **count metric** in contrast, the agent sums up all the values reported in the flush interval.

More details about flush interval [here](https://help.datadoghq.com/hc/en-us/articles/211545826-Why-histogram-stats-are-all-the-same-inaccurate-Characteristics-of-Datadog-histograms-).

Answer (score 2):

The best metric type would be a `histogram` metric.  This will take multiple values, and pre-aggregate them within a flush window, so you will be able to get things like min/max/sum/avg and various percentiles.

If you run multiple times within a flush window:

- `count` would combine multiple values together, so you would lose the individual numbers, meaning you couldn't easily tell between the process returning a lot of documents, or it returning only a few, but being called a lot
- `gauge`, as mentioned in @narayan's answer, would only keep the latest, making it harder to get thins like the max/min count.

Comment: A lot of metrics docs could benefit from this description.